# How to setup python on_reaction_add to parse a json file with the appropriate names & values for translating the correct language?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, emoji, google-translate

This is for a discord bot to translate languages using google translate API after emoji flag for specific language was chosen and the reaction would be to translate to that language, for ex. US Flag would translate the text to English.

Code for importing the json file with the emoji names and values:

```
import json

with open('emoji_flags.json', 'r') as file:
data = json.load(file)
```

This is the code I was working with before using if and elif but I was told that would be an issue which needed to change. How can I change the code to access the json file, find the correct language name/value, and then translate the correct language based on choosing the right one. I am new to all this so I need to learn more python to be able to understand what code would work for this but any help would be appreciated:

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
channel = reaction.message.channel
if reaction.emoji == '':
    translation = translate_text('en', reaction.message.content)
```

Data from the json file, I am starting out with English to make sure it works correctly before adding other languages:

```
{
":flag_us:" : "en"
}
```

Comment: You already have code to read the JSON file.  You probably want that JSON file in the opposite order, right?  If the language is set to `'en'`, then you want `data[language]` to return `":flag_us:"`.

Comment: @TimRoberts, I believe it's correct because the `":flag_us:"` is the shortcode name for the US flag on discord when you hover over it. As well, the `"en"` is the ISO-639-1 Code on Google Translation API Language Support webpage, I believe it needs to return it because that should trigger the application to translate the text to English. 

While I understand I have the code to read the JSON file, I am trying to figure out what code is needed to parse the code in `on_reaction_add` event in order to translate the messages. I think I said read the code and meant parse I believe, my apologies.

Comment: This is what it says on Google's Languages Support webpage about their ISO-639-1 Codes:

"These languages are specified within a recognition request using language code parameters as noted on this page. Most language code parameters conform to ISO-639-1 identifiers, except where noted.

Translations from any language to any language in this list are supported. The list is updated as new languages are added.
"

Comment: I also decided that I would use `on_raw_reaction_add` instead but I think the same parameters work except it has an additional parameter called `payload`, not sure what it means honestly or if it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

To read from a json file, you were correct that you first have to open it using `file = open()` and then you can read the file into a dict with `data = json.load(file)`, and at the end you will have to close the file again using `file.close()`. To simplify the process with closing the file, you did correctly use the `with` keyword, but you need to indent the code that the file should be opened for:

```py
with open(emoji_flags.json) as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

Now data is a dictionary from which you can later extract data. But first we want to get the emoji:

```py
emoji = payload.emoji.name
```

Also you should use `on_raw_reaction_add`, since `on_reaction_add` only works for cached messages.

Since there is currently no way of getting the emoji name in the way it's in discord (`:flag_us:`), you will have to change the structure of your json file to have the emojis as keys:

```
{
"" : "en"
}
```

Note that the emoji looks different in different platforms and apps, even tho it's the same.

Then you can access the language code with

```py
try: #use try except if it's a different emoji
    language_code = data[emoji]
except KeyError:
    pass
```

This all together would be

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    with open(emoji_flags.json) as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
    emoji = payload.emoji.name
    try: #use try except if it's a different emoji
        language_code = data[emoji]
        channel = await bot.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
        translation = translate_text(language_code, message.content)
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

References:

- [PartialEmoji](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction_add#discord.PartialEmoji)
- [on_raw_reaction_add](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction_add#discord.on_raw_reaction_add)
- [RawReactionActionEvent](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction_add#discord.RawReactionActionEvent)

Comment: I’ll try this out as soon as I have time, I appreciate your assistance with this matter! 

Comment: You used the term bot at both `@bot.event and bot.fetch`. Do I need to use that instead of `@client.event and client.fetch`?

Comment: and:

  <br/>
`@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    emoji = payload.emoji.name
    try:  # use try except if it's a different emoji
        language_code = data[emoji]
        translation = translate_text(language_code,`
  <br/>                                     `client.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id).fetch_message(payload.message_id).content)
    except KeyError:
        pass
client.run(DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN)`

Comment: Yes, you'll have to use `client` instead of `bot` @GuySensei8

Comment: I am still figuring out stack overflow formatting. I apologize if my comments look ugly lol. Thanks for the update.

Comment: How would I embed the translated message so I can make it look user-friendly for my user base? I'd like to have it show their avatar and name with the translated message and maybe even print the original message for reference? @Chuaat

Comment: Maybe best to use chat to help troubleshoot this further, do you use discord @Chuaat? I got a few errors but not sure how to best troubleshoot further?

Comment: Can you give me the errors? @GuySensei8

Comment: I don't have access to the google drive file @GuySensei8

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to adjust it from restricted to anyone who can view the picture. Please see this link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d6gk_TAMNyqW_XWBfozrEuoiM3B57WsB/view?usp=sharing

@Chuaat

Comment: @GuySensei8 I edited it, it should now work

Comment: Thanks! Additionally, what source did you find your emoji at so I can add other emoji flags to my json for other languages? Like this one you provided ---> `{"" : "en"}`.
@Chuaat

Comment: Also, the bot ran but it seems that it may be an issue between the translator.py and the bot.py. I did not receive any error but it had no response to us flag reaction at all when testing. I know that the translator is decoding Unicode in order to be able to read the data. Would you like me to share the code for translator.py @Chuaat?

Comment: @GuySensei8 I use [this](https://emojipedia.org/flag-united-kingdom/) website for the emojis. 
For the second question, did you check whether `translate_text(language_code, message.content)` was executed or not? (For example with a simple `print("Here")``)

Comment: I'll probably have to give it a try tomorrow since I've been working, leaving soon to get a temporary crown done, and have to work on some things at home this evening. @Chuaat